# Add Company Name from shipping address in sales order grid

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order

I have following code in Observer.php, which basically adds "company name" from billing address to sales order grid.

I would like to add also **"name"** *(Account Name/Surname)* and **"shipping_company"** *(Company Name from shipping address)*.

Columns appears just fine, but I get no data/values.

I guess I need to add a couple of join for the database but I have no idea on how to do this.

Any help is appreciated. Here is my code:

```
public function addColumnsToSalesOrderGrid(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $event = $observer->getEvent();
    $this->_grid = $event->getBlock();
    if ($this->_grid instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid) {
        $this->_collection = $this->_grid->getCollection();
        $this->_collection->getSelect()->join(Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('sales/order_address'), "main_table.entity_id = ".Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('sales/order_address').".parent_id",array('company') )->where(Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('sales/order_address').".address_type =  'billing'");

        $columnData = array(
            'header' => 'Company Name',
            'index'  => 'company', // Company Name from billing address
            'type' => 'text',
        );

        $this->_grid->addColumnAfter('company', $columnData, 'created_at');
        $this->_grid->sortColumnsByOrder();



        $columnData = array(
            'header' => 'Name',
            'index'  => 'name', // Account Name/Surname
            'type' => 'text'
        );

        $this->_grid->addColumnAfter('name', $columnData, 'company');
        $this->_grid->sortColumnsByOrder();




        $columnData = array(
            'header' => 'Ship to',
            'index'  => 'shipping_company', // Company Name from shipping address
            'type' => 'text'
        );

        $this->_grid->addColumnAfter('shipping_company', $columnData, 'name');
        $this->_grid->sortColumnsByOrder();



        // rebuild the filters
        $filter = $this->_grid->getParam($this->_grid->getVarNameFilter(), null);
        if (is_null($filter)) {
            $this->_collection->load();
        }
        $this->_collection->clear();
        if (is_string($filter)) {
            $data = $this->_grid->helper('adminhtml')->prepareFilterString($filter);
            $this->_setFilterValues($data);
        } else {
            if ($filter && is_array($filter)) {
                $this->_setFilterValues($filter);
            }
        }
        // force a reload of the collection
        $this->_collection->load();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try below code

```
public function addColumnsToSalesOrderGrid(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $event = $observer->getEvent();
    $this->_grid = $event->getBlock();
    if ($this->_grid instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid) {
        $this->_collection = $this->_grid->getCollection();

        $select = $this->_collection->getSelect();
        $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
        $select->join(
            array('order' => $resource->getTableName('sales/order')),
            'main_table.entity_id = order.entity_id',
            array('name' => 'customer_firstname')
        );

        $select->join(
            array('billing' => $resource->getTableName('sales/order_address')),
            'order.billing_address_id = billing.entity_id',
            array('billing_company' => 'company')
        );

        $select->joinLeft(
            array('shipping' => $resource->getTableName('sales/order_address')),
            'order.shipping_address_id = shipping.entity_id',
            array('shipping_company' => 'company')
        );


        $columnData = array(
            'header' => 'Company Name',
            'index'  => 'billing_company', // Company Name from billing address
            'type' => 'text',
        );

        $this->_grid->addColumnAfter('billing_company', $columnData, 'created_at');
        $this->_grid->sortColumnsByOrder();



        $columnData = array(
            'header' => 'Name',
            'index'  => 'name', // Account Name/Surname
            'type' => 'text'
        );

        $this->_grid->addColumnAfter('name', $columnData, 'billing_company');
        $this->_grid->sortColumnsByOrder();




        $columnData = array(
            'header' => 'Ship to',
            'index'  => 'shipping_company', // Company Name from shipping address
            'type' => 'text'
        );

        $this->_grid->addColumnAfter('shipping_company', $columnData, 'name');
        $this->_grid->sortColumnsByOrder();



        // rebuild the filters
        $filter = $this->_grid->getParam($this->_grid->getVarNameFilter(), null);
        if (is_null($filter)) {
            $this->_collection->load();
        }
        $this->_collection->clear();
        if (is_string($filter)) {
            $data = $this->_grid->helper('adminhtml')->prepareFilterString($filter);
            $this->_setFilterValues($data);
        } else {
            if ($filter && is_array($filter)) {
                $this->_setFilterValues($filter);
            }
        }
        // force a reload of the collection
        $this->_collection->load();
    }
}
```

**EDIT :** (Not Tested)

To add two field use Renderer

```
$columnData = array(
                'header' => 'Name',
                'index'  => 'name', // Account Name/Surname
                'type' => 'text'
                'renderer' => new Company_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Renderer_Getname() 
            );
```

in your module

```
<?php 
class Company_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Renderer_Getname extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract
{
    public function render(Varien_Object $row)
    {
         return $row->getFirstname().' '.$row->getLastname();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Gopal, thank you for your help. It seems to work properly. Is it possible to display customer full name (first name + last name) instead of customer_firstname ?

Comment: @Antony try updated answer and let me know the status

Comment: it is not clear to me how to integrate the "Company_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Renderer_Getname" part with existing code, should I create a new module?

Comment: Upps wrong code pasted before, you can use existing module just create block renderer file in it. @Antony

Comment: I added to Observer : `public function render(Varien_Object $row)
    {
         return $row->getFirstname().' '.$row->getLastname();
    }` just before: `public function addColumnsToSalesOrderGrid(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)` Is that the right place?

Comment: no renderer must be in block @Antony

Comment: I'll accept your answer even if I did not manage to display Name+Lastname, maybe I'll ask a new question more specific on this.

Comment: upss sry will try to solve your query on this weekend if possible  @Antony

Answer (score 0):

You can add all these fields and more using the BL CustomGrid extension. It's free and available on GitHub here: https://github.com/mage-eag/mage-enhanced-admin-grids

Although it says it's un-maintained, we have been using it with great success in many stores for years now. It works great in v1.9.3.2.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, but I'd prefer not to use an extension.